# Windows 10 Bootable ISO Install Keeps Failing (0x8007025D)

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, iso-image, windows-installation

Update: The problem turned out to actually be the Kexin USB drive. Windows Install worked fine through a newly purchased SanDisk drive. What made this so hard to debug was that the Kexin drive worked fine for many other things including Memtest, Parted Magic, Diskgenius.

I've tried 3 different Windows 10 builds (1709, 1903, 20H2), mounted them onto an 32gb usb drive via rufus, tried both mbr and gpt, for which I had to switch around my harddrive format even. All three times, the installation process fails usually at 12% of installing the files.

Here the error is described in detail: [https://appuals.com/windows-cannot-install-required-files-0x8007025d/#:~:text=Corrupt%20data%20may%20be%20from,unreadable%20at%20a%20certain%20section](https://appuals.com/windows-cannot-install-required-files-0x8007025d/#:%7E:text=Corrupt%20data%20may%20be%20from,unreadable%20at%20a%20certain%20section).

How can a new usb drive, latest rufus, three different isos keep failing during the install process? I've swapped out my 4 ram sticks, tried the install with each one missing respectively to rule out problems there, no success. I've run a hard drive diagnostic tool by Diskgenius, only one bad sector found and repaired it. Now running memtest86, which found 2 errors. Could those be the reason?

Anybody have experience with this or know how to get more information on this error message and from where it's originating? It's unfortunate that windows doesn't give you more detail on why something doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just trying to understand where the root of the problem might be.

Comment: “Now running memtest86, which found 2 errors. Could those be the reason?” - Yes

Comment: I ran through a long memtest86 for all 4 different ram sticks, it turned out 3 of them have errors, quite bad I guess, one of them though luckily had no errors despite 8 test passes, all green. However, even with only that good ram stick being used, the install still fails with the same corrupt files message :/ this just doesn't make any sense

Comment: The usb drive is brand new, I used the latest rufus, tried different windows build with legit isos, tried both mrb and gpt, I don't really know what's left as possibility. Cpu broken? Motherboard broken?

Comment: Instead of Rufus have you tried simply using the Media Creation Tool instead?  Unless you remove the processor, the processor is unlikely to be broken, since really the only thing on a processor that typically goes bad is a bent pin

Comment: I have not yet tried the Media Creation Tool, will do that. Although it seems like noone has ever had problems with rufus

Comment: I assume `0x8007025D` actually happens when you booted into the installation media and you are not getting it from within Windows?  What brand is this flash drive?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's a Kexin 32GB USB 2.0 drive. I've ordered a new one from Sandisk now to make sure it's not the problem. For the record, this kexin drive worked well for lots of other purposes (diskgenius, parted magic, memtest).
I've also updated my bios, disabled secure boot, completely cleaned my disk via diskpart, and thing still don't work. There is absolute no explanation for this illogical behavior. It can neither find the license terms when I enter a key, nor can it install if I skip the key part, it keeps crashing at 1% of transfering the files...

Comment: like, everything is clean about my pc, all parts should be working, I checked cpu with some math tests and stress tools, checked ram, checked disk, cleaned disk, updated bios to latest driver. It does not make sense.

Comment: Since you took so long to answer my comment, I lost my research, I suspected the brand of flash drive due to finding evidence pointing to a specific brand.

Comment: Update: The install worked fine with my new SanDisk usb drive I ordered. Very weird behavior of the Kexin drive because many things (parted magic, memtest, diskgenius) worked fine and were bootable through that drive, just windows 10 wouldn't....